# Rolling max with pandas on large datasets is very slow

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df` which has a DatatimeIndex spanning about 2 years, 2 columns and over 30 million rows of float64 data.  I quickly noticed that there is a stark difference in performance between `df.rolling('1d').mean()` and `df.rolling('1d').max()`

```
>>> n=100000; import timeit; r=df[:n].rolling('1d'); timeit.timeit(lambda: r.max(), number=1)
2.5886592870228924
>>> n=100000; import timeit; r=df[:n].rolling('1d'); timeit.timeit(lambda: r.mean(), number=1)
0.011829487979412079
>>> n=1000000; import timeit; r=df[:n].rolling('1d'); timeit.timeit(lambda: r.max(), number=1)
53.8340517100296
>>> n=1000000; import timeit; r=df[:n].rolling('1d'); timeit.timeit(lambda: r.mean(), number=1)
0.06093513499945402
```

As you can see, `df.rolling('1d').mean()` is several hundred times faster than `df.rolling('1d').max()`.  I would expect it to be somewhat faster since to calculate the maximum pandas presumably has to keep track the order of all values in the rolling window at each step.  However, it's easy to see how to implement this by adding at most a log factor, so I would expect a smaller difference.  If this is the best one can do, using `df.rolling('1d').max` is going to be a pain on the full dataset, since it looks like it will take hours each time.

Having run into efficiency issues with pandas before (Series.iloc indexing), I am curious as to whether this is a pandas issue or if there is a faster way to solve this problem.

## Edit

This was recently fixed in the master branch of pandas.  Even on the full dataset, the rolling maximum can now be computed in 2.35 seconds whereas before it probably would have taken hours.  Thanks to hexgnu for the fix.

```
>>> runtime(lambda: df.rolling('1d').max())
2.3093386580003425
>>> n=100000; import timeit; r=df[:n].rolling('1d'); timeit.timeit(lambda: r.max(), number=1)
0.015023122999991756
>>> n=1000000; import timeit; r=df[:n].rolling('1d'); timeit.timeit(lambda: r.max(), number=1)
0.08013121400290402
>>> n=10000000; import timeit; r=df[:n].rolling('1d'); timeit.timeit(lambda: r.max(), number=1)
0.6795377829985227
>>> import timeit; r=df.rolling('1d'); timeit.timeit(lambda: r.max(), number=1)
2.3540661859951797
>>> len(df)
32819278
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandas is using naive implementation of running max, with [linear scan over the window for every sample](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/window.pyx#L1215). Thus, it is linear complexity times size of the window, i.e. for few hundred+ samples per day it will be hundred times slower than the mean.

Possible workaround: take by minutes, then over this max by hours, then days - it should result in a kind of log effect, but constants might eat up all asymptotic advantage.

Better solution: contribute heap min_max implementation to pandas

Comment: Judging by the quality of OP's question, there's a good chance they will take your last suggestion. +1 for making it. Good work to you both.

Comment: Here’s and issue for this: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19521. it’s actually pretty straightforward to do this